# scheme to open a youtube playlist on a iOS device

Tags: youtube, uri, url-scheme

I want to know a scheme to open a Youtube playlist.

I have this code:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString      stringWithFormat:@"youtube://playlist?list=PLgrYntDWyYDdHwZney5QoTDFQrphRmYoK"]]]//https://twitter.com/cms24es
    ) {

}else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/TmrrrsApp"]]]//https://twitter.com/cms24es
          ) {

}
```

I know a scheme to open a video, if I use `youtube://`, but to open a playlist instead I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess youtube doesn't understand browser URL of playlist like this -

```
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgrYntDWyYDdHwZney5QoTDFQrphRmYoK
```

Alternatively, go to your video->playlist - [image: Your playlist]

Right click on the playlist and select "copy link address"

[image: Copy Link Address]

It provides a link something like this -

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILwOQV32rHg&list=FLLpWow4PGIVkCJifJxrMfwA
```

Use this as a URI to play in native youtube app.

```
youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILwOQV32rHg&list=FLLpWow4PGIVkCJifJxrMfwA
```