# Is there ANY way to provide a link to a playlist in the YouTube iOS App that will actually work?

Tags: ios, mobile, youtube

I've tried maybe 6 different permutations of YouTube playlist sharing links and none of them will bring you to the playlist on iOS browsers when it transfers you over to the YouTube app (or if it stays in the browser for that matter).

What it does is it goes to the individual video page for the starting point of the playlist, but it's not the actual playlist view, which IS accessible only if you go through the playlists tab within the YouTube mobile app.

Does anyone know if there's an answer or if YouTube just doesn't want me going to a playlist view in its app when clicking the link on my mobile device?

Simple summary:
All I want to do is put a link in my website that will (in a mobile browser) take me to a playlist in the proper playlist view (where it continues on to the next video after the current one is done) either via the YouTube app switch or simply in the mobile browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because Youtube doesn't understand browser URL of playlist like this -

```
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgrYntDWyYDdHwZney5QoTDFQrphRmYoK
```

Alternatively, go to your video->playlist in youtube

Right click on the playlist and select "copy link address"

It provides a link something like this -

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILwOQV32rHg&list=FLLpWow4PGIVkCJifJxrMfwA
```

Use this as a URI to play in native youtube app.

```
youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILwOQV32rHg&list=FLLpWow4PGIVkCJifJxrMfwA
```

Now, when the youtube app is launched it navigates to your playlist and continues to play all the videos in your playlist one by one.

For more info - you can check my answer to similar question here -
[Youtube URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424293/scheme-to-open-a-youtube-playlist-on-a-ios-device/19981964#19981964)

Comment: Thank you San.  I tested this with just the first link example and I didn't realize that the "youtube://" was the key to making it a URI.  It works now.  It was confusing at first, since I'm not sure what this URI stuff is.